# How to reset position of data row changed by next?

Tags: axapta

I want to do while cycles on selected datarows without need of select them again and again. So I want just set the rows back to the starting position. The code should look like:

```
Table table;
select * from table where …;
while(table)
{
    info(table.stringColumn);
    next table;
}
somehow reset table position 
//start from first selected row
while(table)
{
    info(table.stringColumn);
    next table;
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have used `QueryRun` and its method `reset`.

However if you just don't want to get the data from a DB again after it's already been retrieved you can just store all retrieved records in `RecordLinkList`, more info online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/recordlinklist.aspx

If you need examples of code with `QueryRun` or `RecordLinkList` please let me know, I'll add it to the answer.

**P.S.** If you are only interested in stringColumn from your example, just store its values in a container or a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/list.aspx), and go through it afterwards where required.